# Are the nakshatras of Hindu gods and figures discussed in the scriptures?

Tags: nakshatra

I have heard from multiple people, even priests, that Krishna was born in the star *Rohini*. My mother tells me that Kartikeya (a.k.a. Subrahmanya) was born in the star *Pooyam*; Arjuna, in *Uthrattathi*; and Shri Rama, in *Punartham*.

Are there any scriptural references for these? If so, is it true that a person born under a character's/God's nakshatra be influenced by that character/God?

**Edit:**
Pooyam -> Pushya; Uthrattathi -> Uttara Bhadrapada; Punartham -> Punarvasu

Comment: @ManuKumar I see. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is scriptural references for the birth of the Gods you have mentioned. I will answer for the birth star of Rama and Krishna. Birth star of Lord Krishna can be found in Bhagavatha purana tenth canto. I am reproducing the  translation from [here](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/3/1-5/).

> SB 10.3.1-5: Thereafter, at the auspicious time for the appearance of the Lord, the entire universe was surcharged with all the qualities of goodness, beauty and peace. The **constellation Rohiṇī appeared**, as did stars like Aśvinī. The sun, the moon and the other stars and planets were very peaceful. All directions appeared extremely pleasing, and the beautiful stars twinkled in the cloudless sky. Decorated with towns, villages, mines and pasturing grounds, the earth seemed all-auspicious. The rivers flowed with clear water, and the lakes and vast reservoirs, full of lilies and lotuses, were extraordinarily beautiful. In the trees and green plants, full of flowers and leaves, pleasing to the eyes, birds like cuckoos and swarms of bees began chanting with sweet voices for the sake of the demigods. A pure breeze began to blow, pleasing the sense of touch and bearing the aroma of flowers, and when the brāhmaṇas engaging in ritualistic ceremonies ignited their fires according to Vedic principles, the fires burned steadily, undisturbed by the breeze. Thus when the birthless Lord Viṣṇu, the Supreme Personality of Godhead, was about to appear, the saints and brāhmaṇas, who had always been disturbed by demons like Kaṁsa and his men, felt peace within the core of their hearts, and kettledrums simultaneously vibrated from the upper planetary system.

Similarly, Valmiki Ramayana mentions the atrological details regarding the birth of Rama in the eighteenth sarga of Balakanda the translation of which I am reproducing from [here](https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/sloka?field_kanda_tid=1&language=dv&field_sarga_value=18).

> VR 1.18.8-10: Six seasons (one year) passed after the completion of the sacrifice. In the twelfth month of Chaitra on the ninth day (of the bright fortnight), **with Aditi as presiding deity when the star Punarvasu was in the ascendent** and the five planets Sun, Mars, Saturn, Jupiter and Venus, were exalted in their own house in karkata lagna, when Brihaspati was in conjunction with the Moon, Kausalya gave birth to a son: a facet of Visnu, Lord of the entire universe who received obeisance from all the worlds and was adorned with all auspicious signs, the venerable one to perpetuate the Ikshvaku race.

It is not necessary that a person born under the aforementioned nakshatras will be influenced by that God.

Comment: Quote only relevant information what is needed for the answer. Looks like you copied a lot more information for saying Rohini is the constellation of Krishna. Copy paste is discouraged.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Are such references not available for Arjuna's nakshatra or Kartikeya's?

Comment: @AravindSuresh I am not sure which scripture discusses birth nakshatra of Karthikeya. I checked with K M Ganguli's translation of Mahabharatha. There is no mention of Arjuna's birth star. But, Yudhistira's birth star is mentioned to be Jyeshta. https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01124.htm

Answer (score 2):

Yes, its mentioned that Krishna was born in Rohini nakshatra while Rama was born in Punarvasu nakshatra

[Srimada Bhagavatam Canto 10:Chapter 3](http://bhagavata.org/canto10/chapter3.html)

> S'rî S'uka said: 'Then there was the supremely auspicious hour that,
>   with the constellation of **Rohinî rising,** was endowed with all
>   qualities. All the stars and planets stood in a favorable position.

Krishna's horoscope [based on Surdas poem](http://www.kamakotimandali.com/blog/index.php?p=339&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1)

> Samvat saras vibhavan, Bhado aath tithi budhvaar, Krishan paksh Rohini, Ardh nisi harshan jogudaar, Vrish hai lagan, ucha ke nisipati, tanhi bahutsukh pe hai,
>   Chauthe sinh rasi ke dinkar, jiti sakal mahi lehey, Panchvey budh kanya ko jo hai, putrani bahut bade hai, Chatvey shukra tula ke shani jut datru rahan nahipe hai, Unch neech yuvati bahu kari hai, satvey rahu pare hai, Bhagye bhavan mei maker mahi sut, nahu aishvarya bade hai, Laabh bhavan mei meen brihaspati, nav nidhi ghar mei aihey, Karam bhavan ke iis, sanichar syam baran tan aihey, Aadi sanavan parbra ham prabhu, ghat-ghat antarjami, Sau tumhare avtarey aani ke, Surdass ke swami.

[image]

```
 Lord Krishna's horoscope
```

Moon sign in Taurus of Venus planet made Krishna beautiful and loved by many like Gopis, Neechbhanga Ketu in ascendant made Krishna to liberate several souls in his lifetime. Sun sign in Leo and 4th house of wealth made Krishna to be powerful wealthy king.

Birth rashi of Lord Rama is mentioned in Bala Kanda of Ramayana as Punarvasu as Rashi is decided by Moon Sign in a horoscope.

[Bala Kanda, Ramayana by Valmiki, Chapter (Sarga) 18](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/bala/sarga18/bala_18_frame.htm)

> 18:8,9,10,11 On completion of the ritual six seasons have passed by
>   and then in the twelfth month, on the ninth day of chaitra month
>   [April-May,] when the presiding deity of ruling star of the day is
>   Aditi, where the ruling star of day is punarvasu, the asterism is in
>   the ascendant, and when five of the nine planets viz., Sun, Mars,
>   Jupiter, Saturn, and Venus are at their highest position, when Jupiter
>   with Moon is ascendant in Cancer, and when day is advancing, then
>   Queen Kausalya gave birth to a son with all the divine attributes like
>   lotus-red eyes, lengthy arms, roseate lips, voice like drumbeat, and
>   who took birth to delight the Ikshwaku dynasty, who is adored by all
>   the worlds, and who is the greatly blessed epitome of Vishnu, namely
>   Rama.

[image]

```
 Lord Rama's horoscope
```

Moon sign in Cancer of dynamic Moon planet made Rama to do lot of travels in his life with Jupiter making him wise and forming Gajkesari Yoga with Moon, and Sun sign in Aries of Mars planet and house of profession made him natural king.

> 18:15 The fair-minded Bharata is born under Pisces where puSyami is the star
>   of day, and the sons of Sumitra, namely Lakshmana and Shatrughna are
>   born under Cancer, where ashlesha is the star of the day and when sun
>   is rising.

Also, birth constellation of Bharata is Pushya with ascendant Pisces,and of twins Laxmana-Shatrughana, brothers of Rama is Ashlesha with ascendant Cancer. The lord and symbol of Ashlesha nakshatra is Naga or Hydra, which is also an another name of [Sheshanaag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shesha), whose avatar were Laxman-Shatrughana. All three Pushyami, Punarvasu-4 and Ashlesha nakshatra are part of Cancer(Kataka) ruled by Moon and as the Moon sign of the 4 brothers Rama, Bharata, Laxmana, Shatrughana, hence made them highly compatible with each other.

[image]

For the full effect of constellation to take place luminaries(Sun and Moon) should be strong in degrees and in the Kendra(1,4,7,10) houses without combustion. For example in both the horoscopes of Rama and Krishna, Sun and Moon are at 90 degrees which shows that Rama was born on Shukla Navami(9th)(Moon is ahead of Sun by 4 houses) while Krishna was born in Krishna Ashtmi(8th)(Moon is behind Sun by 4 houses) which are around in the middle of Shukla and Krishna Paksha of 15 days. Full moon(Sun and Moon aspecting) or No moon(Sun and Moon in conjunction) causes combustion of Moon(mind) with Sun(soul) and is not regarded as auspicious as the middle of Pakshas. In these cases, ascendant is same as Moon sign, but usually for normal persons, Sun sign, Moon sign and Ascendant(Body nature) all three should be analyzed to predict about the attributes of any person.